# model Shop::Product looking table shop_products. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following model
models/shop/product.rb

```
class Shop::Product
end
```

I generated migration

```
def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      # ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

I create new product and display error **UndefinedTable: ERROR:  "shop_products"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> model Shop::Product looking table shop_products. Why?

[Because of Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html):

> The Inflector transforms words from singular to plural, ***class names
>   to table names***, modularized class names to ones without, and class
>   names to foreign keys.

By Rails convention you should change the db table name to `shop_products`.

If you want to have a different talbe name than model's name implies, you should specify the `table_name`:

```
class Shop::Product
  self.table_name = :products
end
```